# how to access from nested form group (the name property as an array)?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I need to access the second formBuilder group section to iterate (name and age property)Im having trouble with how deep the nested elements are. How can I iterate name and age over a div based on its level in the form group

```
this.requestForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          dept:[''],
        }),        
        this.formBuilder.group({
            formRow: this.formBuilder.array([
              this.initSingle(),  
            ])
          }),
        // Step 3
        this.formBuilder.group({
          email: [''],
        })   
      ]),
    })
}   

initSingle(){
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [0],
      name: [''],
      age: ['']
    })
  }
```

```
<div *ngFor="let X of requestForm['controls'].formArray['controls'][1]; let i = index">
```

Comment: Looks to me that you don't want to use a FormArray, I would make it a nested group. Usually in formarrays we have formgroups that have same properties, in your array all formgroups are different.

Comment: thanks but there is a add method that will duplicate the form row, so the nested formGroup with formRow will have duplicate copies.

Comment: OK, so sounds to me you want to push formgroups of these 3 subformgroups into a formarray.

Comment: or is it only formrow that is duplicated? If so, why are the other subgroups inside the formarray?

Comment: formRow should be duplicated so lets say 3 users sign up i need initSingle() to run 3 times so I can get the values of id name and age

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that `dept` and `email` don't need to be inside the formarray, you only want to duplicate the `formRow`, so I placed `dept` and `email` in the parent group, and then we can just iterate the formarray in template:

```ts
this.requestForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  dept: [''],
  email: [''],
  formRow: this.formBuilder.array([this.initSingle()]),
});
```

I use a getter for the formarray to get the correct typings, casting it as an `FormArray`:

```ts
get formRow() {
  return this.requestForm.get('formRow') as FormArray;
}
```

and the iteration in template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="requestForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input formControlName="email" placeholder="email"/>
  <!-- More code here... -->
  <div formArrayName="formRow">
    <div *ngFor="let row of formRow.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="name" placeholder="formrow name"/>
      <!-- More code here... -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```